# Calculate a sum from hidden columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table which looks like:

[image]

The Strike Rate basically works out the OrdersTaken - OrdersFrom, but I don't want these two columns to show, so I would like just the Code + Strike Rate Calls

But when I disable show, it prompts me asking to enter in the numbers for it, so it's not being able to find it anymore?

[image]

My query looks like something like:

```
SELECT T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.AccreditedDomainCode,
    Count(T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory.CustomerCode)
        AS OrdersTaken, qry_TargetReports.CountOfCustomerCode 
        AS OrdersFrom, [OrdersTaken]-[OrdersFrom] 
        AS [Strike Rate (Calls)]

    FROM qry_TargetReports 
        INNER JOIN (T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls
        INNER JOIN T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory 
            ON (T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.CallDate = T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory.EntryDate)
                AND (T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.CustomerCode = T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory.CustomerCode)) 
            ON qry_TargetReports.AccreditedDomainCode = T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.AccreditedDomainCode

    GROUP BY T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.AccreditedDomainCode, qry_TargetReports.CountOfCustomerCode;
```

But to be honest, MsAccess Generated it for me. I just need a method on how I can hide two columns while still calculating the sum, cheers.

Comment: Please don't link images in your question, many folks can't see them (or they've been taken down). Can you instead post the tables as text?

Comment: Is it a saved query? Queries have sort order associated with them that is automatically saved. A prompt like this often indicates that the field you are non longer using is saved in the sort order.

Comment: It's not a saved query, I take the SQL code and place it into VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use everything you have now except `[OrdersTaken]-[OrdersFrom]` as a subquery and calculate that difference in the parent query.

The problem was that `[OrdersTaken]` and `[OrdersFrom]` are both aliases for field expressions, and the original query attempted to use those alias names in the `SELECT` clause when computing `[Strike Rate (Calls)]`.  Generally Access won't let you do that.

```sql
SELECT
    sub.AccreditedDomainCode,
    (sub.OrdersTaken - sub.OrdersFrom) AS [Strike Rate (Calls)]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            rdc.AccreditedDomainCode,
            Count(rpsh.CustomerCode) AS OrdersTaken,
            tr.CountOfCustomerCode AS OrdersFrom
        FROM
            qry_TargetReports AS tr
            INNER JOIN (T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls AS rdc
            INNER JOIN T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory AS rpsh
            ON
                    (rdc.CallDate = rpsh.EntryDate)
                AND (rdc.CustomerCode = rpsh.CustomerCode)) 
            ON tr.AccreditedDomainCode = rdc.AccreditedDomainCode
        GROUP BY rdc.AccreditedDomainCode, tr.CountOfCustomerCode
    ) AS sub;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the SELECT : there are 4 parts corresponding to the 4 result columns

```
T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.AccreditedDomainCode,
Count(T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory.CustomerCode) AS OrdersTaken,
qry_TargetReports.CountOfCustomerCode AS OrdersFrom
[OrdersTaken]-[OrdersFrom] AS [Strike Rate (Calls)]
```

If you want only the 1st and the 4th, just drop the 2nd and 3st line :

```
T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.AccreditedDomainCode,
[OrdersTaken]-[OrdersFrom] AS [Strike Rate (Calls)]
```

BUT, you also have to replace OrdersTaken and OrdersFrom by their definitions :

```
T_Temp_RestrictedDiaryCalls.AccreditedDomainCode,
Count(T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory.CustomerCode) # this is what OrdersTaken stands for
    - qry_TargetReports.CountOfCustomerCode # this is what OrdersFrom stands for
AS [Strike Rate (Calls)]
```

Note that you can also set

```
Strike Rate (Calls):Count(T_Temp_RestrictedProductSalesHistory.CustomerCode)-qry_TargetReports.CountOfCustomerCode
```

in the query definition of your editor, this will do the same.